# Module build failed , Duplicate declaration

Tags: reactjs, webpack-dev-server

I am following Microsoft Tutorial regarding React JS, in the first part, the example has an app.js are rendering through react to an index.html, before that i need to run the start-webpack-server to setup the localhost8080. but i cant get through this, after \ npm run start-webpack-server, i got error as:

Duplicate declaration "InboxPane"

the code is as follows:

app.js

```
var React = require('react');
var ReactDOM = require('react-dom');
import InboxPane  from './../../../../05_ES6/Code/fork-es6/app/components/InboxPane';

var App = React.createClass({
    render: function(){

        return (
            <div>
             <div id = 'header'> </div>
             <div className = "container"> 
                 <div className = "column">
                 <InboxPane /> 
                 </div>
             </div>
            </div>
        )
    }

});

var InboxPane = React.createClass ({
    render: function(){
        return (
            <div id = 'inbox-pane'>
                <h1>Inbox</h1>
            </div>
        )
    }

});

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('main'));
```

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Pizza Chain Bot Manager</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/app/app.css">
</head>
<body>
  <div id="main">
  </div>

  <script src="/bundle.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

error message on command line after npm run start-webpack-server:

```
ERROR in ./app/app.js
Module build failed: 
C:/ReactMVA master/02_ReactIntroduction/Code/start/app/app.js: Duplicate 
  declaration "InboxPane"

     20 | });
  21 |
> 22 | var InboxPane = React.createClass ({
     |     ^
  23 |     render: function(){
  24 |         return (
  25 |             <div id = 'inbox-pane'>

 @ multi (webpack)-dev-server/client?http://localhost:8080 webpack/hot/dev-
 server ./index.html ./app.js
  webpack: Failed to compile.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It just seems Webpack can't find `babel-loader` and `file-loader`. If these are in your `package.json` then `npm install` should do the trick. Else, install them using `npm install babel-loader file-loader --dev`.

Comment: hi, thanks !!  the previous mistake gone, but i got the error as following : ERROR in ./app/app.js ,    Module build failed: Error: Couldn't find preset "react" relative to directory "C:\\ReactMVA-master\\02_ReactIntroduction\\Code\\start\\app" @ multi (webpack)-dev-server/client?

Comment: Your project seems to miss some dependencies... Anyway, to fix it do `npm install babel-preset-react --save-dev`

Comment: Thanks Man, i think i am geting close, however the issue i have right now is Duplicate declaration "InboxPane" , i will edit this issue to show it clearer , comments can not explain well

Comment: VSCode added an `import` on the top on your file. Remove the line 3 `import InboxPane  from ...`

Comment: finally it works ! eventhough i dont know why the vscode added that line for me, but thanks !